# Der Stolz auf was wir tun

Tags: sentence-structure, comma, relative-clause

Eine Privatbank hat kürzlich ein ganzseitiges Inserat mit folgendem Claim geschaltet:

> Der Stolz, auf was wir tun, wird nur übertroffen durch den Stolz auf
>   das, was wir nicht tun.

Gemeint war, dass sie nicht nur auf ihren Geschäftserfolg stolz sind, sondern noch mehr auf ihre Geschäftsethik, und dass sie darum gewisse Dinge nicht tun. Das ist natürlich löblich, aber der Satz scheint mir nicht ganz aufzugehen.

Normalweise würde ich korrigieren zu: «Der Stolz auf das, was wir tun». Ist das Demonstrativpronomen «das» eigentlich zwingend oder ist «Der Stolz auf was wir tun» auch korrekt? Und wenn ja, wo kommen die Kommas hin?

Comment: Hm, ich denke, dass "Der Stolz auf/über was wir tun" wäre in Ordnung. Genauso wie "Der Stolz auf/über das, was wir tun". Nur nicht nicht "Der Stolz, auf/über was wir tun". Sprich, das erste Komma muss weg.  — ["über" ist, denke ich, regional.]

Comment: "Stolz sein über etwas" gehört jedenfalls nicht zum Kanon der klassischen deutschen Sprache. In diesem oder jenem isolierten Linguotop mag die eine oder andere Sumpfblüte ihr Dasein fristen, aber Standard (und gutes Vorbild) ist das nicht. Standard (und gutes Vorbild) ist nach wie vor "stolz sein **auf** etwas".

Comment: Auf etwas stolz zu sein, was man nicht (selber? eigenhändig?) tut, ist übrigens etwas anderes, als darauf stolz zu sein, etwas nicht zu tun.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper. Richtig. Das ist sogar eigentlich der üblere Schnitzer in diesem vollkommen missratenen Werbespruch.

Comment: Richtig ist "Der Stolz auf das, was ...". Der Werbespruch ist auch inkonsistent: Am Anfang wird "Der Stolz auf was ..." gesagt, am Ende "Der Stolz auf das, was ...".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Sprachlich missraten ja, aber dennoch hat der Werbespruch eine klare und verständliche Botschaft. Ob das auch so praktiziert wird, steht auf einem anderen Blatt. Immerhin wurde erreicht, dass auch in diesem Forum darüber reflektiert wird ;--)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die von dir zitierte Privatbank leidet an akuter Angloamerikanitis. Es ist zwar guter englischer Stil, zu sagen *I am proud of what I am doing* (und Kenner schätzen die englische Sprache wegen ihrer eleganten Kürze), aber im Deutschen, sofern man auf korrekten Ausdruck und guten Stil wert legt, heißt es zwingend auch heute noch:

> Ich bin stolz auf das, was ich tue.

Ein Satz wie der zitierte würde vom Schullehrer mit roter Tinte, vom Zeitungsredakteur mit Korrekturmarken gekennzeichnet, auf dass der Schüler es künftig besser mache und die Setzerei (da wo's noch eine gibt) den missratenen Satz verbessere. Hat der Schüler das geschafft, kann er stolz sein **auf das, was** er geschrieben hat. (Nicht aber "auf was er geschrieben hat".) Die Setzerei wird nicht unbedingt stolz sein, denn solchen Murks zu beseitigen gehört für sie  <strike>zu was sie täglich macht</strike> **zu dem, was** sie täglich macht.

Der Privatbank wäre zu raten, sich Folgendes zu Herzen zu nehmen:

> The quality of how we write indicates the quality of how we deal with your money.

Hoffentlich doch aber nicht:

> <strike>Die Qualität von wie wir schreiben zeigt die Qualität von wie wir mit Ihrem Geld umgehen.</strike>

Comment: Was 1 nices Beispiel vong Deutlichkeit her.